# How to clearly present titles for each data on my bar plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have an array

```
a  = ['Film & Video', 'Fashion', 'Art', 'Games', 'Music', 'Publishing', 'Technology', 'Music', 'Theater',.....'Dance', 'Art', 'Film & Video']
```

I used pandas to make a frequency count of the strings in the array to make the plot

```
import pandas
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

letter_counts = Counter(a)
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(letter_counts, orient='index')
df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.xlabel('Category')
plt.ylabel('Counts')
plt.title("Successful Categories")

plt.show()
```

[image]

You cannot see the title for my x axis or the full name for long strings such as 'Film & Video'. I'm looking for a way to better visualize my plot. Also, how can I remove or edit the box in the top right of the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is one way of slight modification by rotating the tick labels (helps with decreasing the vertical height spanned by the labels), hiding the legend and using a tight layout. I created a sample data and used the following lines (only showing the code partly). I replaced `&` by `and`:

```
letter_counts = Counter(a)
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(letter_counts, orient='index',columns=['values'])
df.plot.bar(y='values', legend=False)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  This was a clean, simply and more visually appealing display for my plot.